# How to focus on a particular paragraph on page?

Tags: joomla1.5

i am working on a joomla site and i have a problem.

**Problem**

I have a menu with some menu items.and say under menu products i have menu items

1. Product A
2. product B
3. Product C

Product A through C are on a single article.
What i want is that when i click the menu item " Product B" it should redirect to the products article page with product B focussed.Similarly for other products.

how can i accomplish this thing ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create your anchors in the article. (i.e. #productA, #productB, #productC)
2. Create a menu item for that article. (i.e. http://www.example.com/products)
3. Create an 'External URL' menu item for each article and include the URL for the 'products' page plus the anchor for that product. (i.e. http://www.example.com/products#productA)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.i tried with what you said.unfortunately , after i click the menu item it does redirect to that article but doesnt take to that spot where the product is

Comment: I just tested it in Joomla 1.5 and 2.5 and it works! which text editor are you using ? is it a joomla article or from a CCK ?

Comment: I am using joomla 1.5 with Tiny MCE editor.Yes its a joomla article.

Answer (score 0):

I would try use anchors.

you can search in Google for "HTML anchors"

or here is example link:

http://www.hypergurl.com/anchors.html

Comment: This is fine .. but how can i accomplish it from my menu ? after a user clicks on product B he must be taken to the specific spot where the Product B description is.I want it done from the menu.